# Android Reading XML file from Folder

Tags: java, android

So I am trying to read a file from the assests folder in my application. I have looked for a solution and every solution it appears the same as what I am doing.

I am perfomring this task in my main file here is the class definition:

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

I then have this in a function located in MainActivity:

```
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    factory.setValidating(false);
    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

    AssetManager manager =getAssets();


    InputStream input = null ;
    try
    {
        input= manager.open("data.xml");
        System.out.println("PASSED");

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("FAILED");
    }

    xpp.setInput(input, null);
```

I have tried alot of differnt options but input is null it never gets a different value.

Any help would be appreciated, I am new to Android programming.

Thanks!

Comment: Presumably, you do not have `data.xml` in the `assets/` directory of your project. Besides, an XML resource is *much* faster to read in. Put your file in `res/xml/data.xml`, then use `getResources().getXml()` to get your `XmlPullParser`.

Comment: I did have data.xml in my assests fodler. So i tried changing my code to yours this is what i have:      XmlPullParser xpp =getResources().getXml(1); I only have one xml file in the xml folder but it didnt like 0 or 1.

Comment: Do not just magically make up numbers to fill in as parameters to methods. The value should be `R.xml.data`, if your file is `res/xml/data.xml`.

Comment: It worked thank you! Sorry I an a noob at android, thanks again for your help!